# How to generate unique (forever) alphanumeric tokens (4 to 8 digits only)

Tags: php

I wonder if there is a way in PHP to generate a unique alphanumeric(case sensitive) tokens that can be unique forever without any collision. If we derive them from the **time stamp** string which is 10 characters like: **1394452319**, that might be possible but I am not sure if we can make the token short up to 4 characters? If not possible then **5, 6, 7 and max is 8** characters. Because I want to generate short tokens to be readable by users.

Tokens should look like: 1aYc, ZoXq, 3iU9, etc.

I don't want to show the users any sequence.

One more thing, my application will be used by more than one user, so in case two users clicked at same time to generate the token, will the PHP application generate the same token (I assume we use the timestamp to generate the token)? How can we prevent from this problem?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, [`Random::alphanumericString($length)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Random) with a `$length` between 4 (inclusive) and 8 (inclusive) does exactly what you want. You could even randomize the length as well if you wanted, e.g. by passing `Random::intBetween(4, 8)`. But this (and also any other solution) has theoretical limits: There can only be 14,776,336 distinct values with 4 characters and 218,340,105,600,000 values with 8 characters (which is a lot, though).

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to have an incremental (i.e. auto_update) id that you keep hidden internally. From that, you generate a hash, representing the id to hide the sequence. The incremented id gets rid of collision problems (i.e. MySQL has an integrated solution for this).

The trick you need to use now is a random hash table consinsting of two columns, both having the values n to m but with the second column being randomized. i.e.

```
col1 | col2
   1 | 2
   2 | 4
   3 | 5
   4 | 1
   5 | 3
```

if you have the randomly sorted number for your incremented number, it is easy to create a hash from that. Just think about your possible chars as numbers. You get it righgt?

Assuming you have a good algorithm for random numbers, you can make a pretty good hash table. However, there also is a way to find an algorithm, providing you with the numbers as they increase. So in this example it would give you `col2 = fn(col1)` so i.e. `4 = fn(2)`. 
All you have to do is take the result and re-enginer it into a formular :D
Otherwise you have to fill the table initially.

To give you a glimpse insight into the math of it, think of a function that uses odd/even characteristics of the number and combines it with addition.

With n digits using a range of 62 possibilitys (*case sensitive letters and numbers*) per char you have 62^n possibilities.
For 4 digits that makes 14776336  possibilities (*62^4*).

Thou that might sound just wonderfull, you can imagine that having a table, prefilled with 14776336 id's is not the cleanest solution.

Still, i hope this at least leads into the right direction.

EDIT:
We started a discussion on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716930/non-sequential-sequence-function). IT has some additional information on how to create a function for our needs.

Comment: Thank you very very much for the detailed solution, it sounds fine but the problem in case I clear the table of IDs and run the system again, the new IDs will be same as the previous ones :( And the collision will happen! That's why I am into timestamp related tokens as the time will not be same all the life. One more thing, would you please provide a sample code for what you have explained? Thank you once again! So useful

Comment: @moderns if you find a method that suits your needs, you don't have to keep/fill the table and will not have collision since you could just use the number of entries as your new starting point for your auto_increase id, or store the auto_incremented id in the same table as the public id.
An example actually would be a lot of work since the last time i did write code like that is 10 years ago and i fail to find a copy :D
As is said, consider asking for such a function in the math section of stack exchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you Andresch, I will try to make a code myself :)

Comment: @moderns Do consider asking the math gurus. They might seem weird, but that's what they think about us right? ;-)

Comment: Hehehe, yes right! Probably I will generate a code from the timestamp which is 10 numbers, each number will represent a set of characters and I will use the rand. For example: 1482334526 = a4tEoPsr5V. For example, the number 1 has =>[a,A,b,B,1], number 2 has =>[c,C,d,D,2], etc. Will that be OK? Thank you!

Comment: @moderns that sounds interesting. Just make sure that you avoid collicion in your function. And keep in mind, the timestamp is not unique since two users might end up on your page and both receive the same timestamp.

Comment: thanks for answering always. My last solution might work if I add a sequence number to each ID generated, but also, the number of characters will be 11 characters :( I aim to get 4 to 8 characters string length :( I will try to make an develop an algorithm which gives me 4 characters string length with a non-sequence out look!

Comment: @moders did i mention you should ask the math nerds?  ;-)

Comment: Yes you did, I am searching for the math nerds! But where to find them? :(

Comment: @moderns As i pointed out, stackexchange has a math section: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry! Thank you very much, I will ask the question now there. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @moderns i already did: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716930/non-sequential-sequence-function

Comment: @moderns you might want to consider marking this answer as accepted. It does answer your question and i did put quite some effort into it didn't i?

Comment: Thanks Andresch, but I didn't reach the code yet :( No body helped me from the Math forum :(

Comment: @moderns i even asked the question for you and got two replys :( look, i posted the link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716930/non-sequential-sequence-function

Answer (score 1):

this is the another function that you can use also

```
<?php 
    function generateRandomString($length = 8) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
       $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

echo generateRandomString();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like following

```
<?php
      // chars
     $chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()-+';

     // convert to array
    $arr = str_split($chars, 1);

    // shuffle the array
    shuffle($arr);

   // array to chars with 8 chars
  echo substr(implode('', $arr), 0, 8);
?>
```

Comment: @moderns try the below code then.. check if it gives u ur suitable result or not..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function :

```
    // RETRUN 24 digit of UNIX ID :
    public function getComplexIDTicket(){  // duplicate method on Rest.php
        $arrAZ1 = range('A','Z');
        $arrAZ2 = range('A','Z');
        $arrAZ3 = range('A','Z');

        $arrs1 = range('A','Z');
        $arrs2 = range('A','Z');
        $arrs3 = range('A','Z');

        $a1 = $arrAZ1[rand(0,25)];
        $a2 = $arrAZ2[rand(0,25)];
        $a3 = $arrAZ3[rand(0,25)];

        $s1 = $arrs1[rand(0,25)];
        $s2 = $arrs2[rand(0,25)];
        $s3 = $arrs3[rand(0,25)];

        $s = $s1.$s2.$s3;

        $t = microtime(true);
        $micro = sprintf("%07d",($t - floor($t)) * 10000000);
        $id = date('ymdHis').strtoupper(dechex(substr($micro,0,7)));
        $id = str_pad($id, 24, $a3.$a2.$a1.$s, STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        // 151106214010 3DDBF0 L D C SM4
        return $id;
    }
```